# How to read a JSON file in Angularjs 1.0?

Tags: html, angularjs, json

I need to read to a JSON format file in angular 1.6 so I do the following

**In Html**

```
    <div ng-model="JsonRendering" ng-controller="NewsRendering">
        <div ng-repeat="NewsData in News">
            <h3>{{NewsData.Title}}</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**In Script**

```
angular
    .module( "JsonRendering", [])
    .controller("NewsRendering", [ "$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'News/News.json'
        }).then(function success(data) {
            $scope.News = data;
        });
    }]);
```

**In JSON**

```
{
  "articles": [

    {
      "Title": "Article 1",

      "Abstract": "Article 1 abstract starts here ...",

      "Body": "Article 1 body starts here....."
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm trying to render only the title but it doesn't work. It shows on the web page `{{NewsData.Title}}`.

**Note:** The json file is a local JSON file inside a folder. So the path of the json file is "Root/News/News.json So what should I do to solve the problem

Comment: $scope.News = JSON.parse(data);

Comment: Open your browser console. Read the error. Fix it. Then realize that you're trying to iterate on the HTTP response, instead of iterating on the articles array of the JSON object which is the body (i.e. the data property) of the response. Using a debugger helps.

Comment: @user3284463 no need to parse. AngularJS does that for you.

Comment: @JBNizet No error at the console.

Comment: Then it means you're not even starting your angular app. The browser probably can't find or load the JS files containing your code.

Comment: @JBNizet no it's working, because it shows some result from angular in the same page

Comment: Hmm, could it be instead `$scope.News = data.articles;` looking at the JSON

Comment: I doubt you don't have any error, then. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, in a plunkr.

Comment: @user3284463 it's not working, anyway thanks

Comment: There are only two possible reasons why Angular wouldn't parse `{{NewsData.Title}}` and you're seeing it as such on the page: either an error is thrown or the HTML isn't on Angular's scope. If it's not the first option, then it's the second. The code you've shown doesn't have anything to do with it. You *really* have to show a demo that we can try ([mcve]) if you want help solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change it as, you should use **`data.data`**

```
.controller("NewsRendering", [ "$scope", "$http", function ($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'News/News.json'
        }).then(function success(data) {
            $scope.News = data.data;
        });
    }]);
```

and your ng-repeat should be,

```
 <div ng-repeat="NewsData in News.articles">
            <h3>{{NewsData.Title}}</h3>
 </div>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/eSP2yPi6VTH6X5FpkiBd?p=preview)**

Comment: Correct, but not sufficient. The OP also needs to iterate on the articles. (I'm not the downvoter).

Comment: It shows {{NewsData.Title}} on the page. No error on the console

Comment: @HTMLMan As JBNizet mention above, your app doesn't seem to have started.

Comment: @Sajeetharan here is the problem I'm using "ng-model=JsonRendering" while you are using "ng-app="JsonRendering". Now it's working, thaks a lot.

Comment: @JBNizet yes it seems so